# How to load a different resource with different unit test methods?

Tags: java, junit

I have about 15 JUnit test cases each one which needs a difference resource file from which it reads necessary input data. Currently, I'm hard coding the specific resource file path in each test case method.

```
@Test
public void testCase1() {
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resource1.txt");
        // more code here
}

@Test
public void testCase2() {
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resource2.txt");
        // more code here
}
```

May be I could have all these files loaded in the `setUp()` method into separate URL variables and then use the specific URL variable in each test method. Is there a way better way of doing this?

Comment: Is each test case exactly the same except for the resource?

Comment: @Jeffrey the assert statements are different for each test case. Other than that, it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JUnit `RunWith(Parameterized.class)`.

Example, that takes a resource name and an int expected result :

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

public class MyTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"resource1.txt", 0000}, {"resource2.txt", 9999}
        });
    }

    public final URL url;
    public final int expected;

    public MyTest(String resource, int expected) {
        this.url=URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/"+resource)
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testReadResource() throws Exception {
        // more code here, based on URL and expected
    }

}
```

More info here:http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`TestName`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) rule.

```
@Rule public TestName testName = new TestName();
public URL url;

@Before
public void setup() {
    String resourceName = testName.getMethodName().substring(4).toLowerCase();
    url = getClass().getResource("/" + resourceName + ".txt");
}

@Test
public void testResource1() {
    // snip
}

@Test
public void testResource2() {
    // snip
}
```